# Can someone explain this code's logic to me?

Tags: c, pthreads

I was practicing multithreading and looking for problems online. But i cannot understand the logic behind this chunk of code.

The code creates 4 threads and sums the 1/4th part of the array. I know how to create threads but cannot understand the sum function.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
// size of array 
#define MAX 100 

// maximum number of threads 
#define MAX_THREAD 4 

int fill_array[100];
int sum[4] = { 0 }; 
int part = 0; 

void* sum_array(void* arg) 
{ 
    int i=0;
    // Each thread computes sum of 1/4th of array 
    int thread_part = part++; 

    for ( i = thread_part * (MAX / 4); i < (thread_part + 1) * (MAX / 4); i++) 
        sum[thread_part] += fill_array[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure this code works as intended? I have a feeling it doesn't.

Comment: The code you showed doesn't create 4 threads. The code you showed looks like to increment `part`. Then it loops over 1/4 of the `fill_array` and sums the values into `sum[]`.

Comment: `part++` isn't thread-safe. You need a lock around that. Better yet, pass `thread_part` as an argument to the thread.

Comment: Whoever wrote that code assumed incorrectly that `part++` is an atomic operation.   It is not - if two threads do that concurrently, one can interrupt the other partway through (e.g. thread A accesses `part`, thread `B` accesses `part` - getting the same value, thread A increments and stores `part`, thread B increments and stores `part` - which means both A and B get the same value of `thread_part`.   This is a classic race condition, due to lack of synchronisation (e.g., using a mutex) when accessing and modifying `part`

Comment: Tip: Defining `MAX_THREAD` is good, but you only if you actually use it! Those `/4` should be `/MAX_THREAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `sum_array` is called, the elements `thread_part * (MAX / 4)` (inclusive) to `(thread_part + 1) * (MAX / 4)` (exclusive) are summed.

- The 1st time `sum_array` is called, `thread_part` is `0`, and `sum_array` will sum elements [0,25) into `sum[0]`.
- The 2nd time `sum_array` is called, `thread_part` is `1`, and `sum_array` will sum elements [25,50) into `sum[1]`.
- The 3rd time `sum_array` is called, `thread_part` is `2`, and `sum_array` will sum elements [50,75) into `sum[2]`.
- The 4th time `sum_array` is called, `thread_part` is `3`, and `sum_array` will sum elements [75,100) into `sum[3]`.

The above is true as long as the calls to `sum_array` are sequential. However, I presume that `sum_array` is being called once by each of four simultaneously-running threads. Because `part++` isn't thread-safe, `thread_part` isn't guaranteed to be different in each thread, so it won't work as nicely as described above.

To achieve the desired result, you need to make `part++` atomic (e.g. using a lock). Better yet, pass `thread_part` as an argument to the thread.

Note that `MAX` must be evenly divisible by `4` or elements won't be summed.

Comment: Thank you for such a beautiful explanation.